# Vectorise np logic: zeroing out in z axis above point

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have an array:

```py
rp = np.array(
    [
        [[True, False], [True, True]],
        [[True, True], [False, True]],
        [[True, True], [True, True]],
        [[True, True], [True, False]],
        [[True, True], [True, True]],
    ]
)
```

I want to zero it out in the z axis above the first `False` point, i.e. set subsequent z values to `False`.  Thus I have a test:

```py
def test_f():
    desired = np.array(
        [
            [[True, False], [True, True]],
            [[True, False], [False, True]],
            [[True, False], [False, True]],
            [[True, False], [False, False]],
            [[True, False], [False, False]],
        ]
    )
    assert (f(rp) == desired).all()
```

And I have some non vectorised code which passes the test:

```py
def f(a: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    lowest = np.argmin(a, axis=0)
    for x, row in enumerate(lowest):
        for y, z in enumerate(row):
            if not a[z, x, y]: # catch cases with no False at all
                a[z:, x, y] = False
    return a
```

How do I vectorise this function?

Comment: `f = lambda rp:np.minimum.accumulate(rp, axis=0)`

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny goodness that was easy.  Could you post it as an answer and I can accept it?  I was sure I was just writing the definition of some function, but I didn't realise you could bound accumulate by an axis.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```py
def f(a: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return a.cumprod(axis=0, dtype=np.bool)
```

Comment: oh!  I'd never heard of cumprod.  This works nicely, although the minimum.accumulate solution is actually more intuitive now I know you can constrain it by axis.  Still if it doesn't get posted I'll accept this.

Comment: 'the frog wrinkled its brow in an effort of calculation.... one ..and one.. was... one!' (for Terry Prattchet fans)

Comment: Yep, `minimum` looks much cheaper than `product`. It should be accepted.

Comment: odd that, I've just done the same timing.  I guess the underlying C code is doing a real multiplication.

Comment: I loop for `1000` times. `np.minimum.accumulate()` is the fastest, `np.cumprod()` is the second, and your original code is the last.